# Is this c++ template param deduction incorrect?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, boost-regex

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
int main(void)
{
    std::cmatch cm;
    std::regex_match("subject", cm, std::regex("(sub)(.*)"));
    //std::for_each(cm.begin(), cm.end(), [](const std::sub_match<const char *> &s){   <---- Working statement

    std::for_each(cm.begin(), cm.end(), [](const std::cmatch &s){ /*<--- Non-working statement*/
        std::cout << "match:" << s.str() <<std::endl;
    });
    return 0;
}
```

The error is as following:

```
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:853:9: error: no matching function for call to object of type '(lambda at main.cpp:73:41)'
 __f(*__first);
 ^~~
 main.cpp:73:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::for_each<std::__1::__wrap_iter<const std::__1::sub_match<const char *> *>, (lambda at main.cpp:73:41)>' requested here
 std::for_each(cm.begin(), cm.end(), [](const std::match_results<const char*> &s){
 ^
 main.cpp:73:41: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const std::__1::sub_match<const char *>' to 'const std::match_results<const char *>' for 1st argument
 std::for_each(cm.begin(), cm.end(), [](const std::match_results<const char*> &s){
 ^
 maintool.cpp:73:41: note: conversion candidate of type 'void (*)(const std::match_results<const char *> &)'
 1 error generated.
```

In non-working example why is template deduced as `std::__1::for_each<std::__1::__wrap_iter<const std::__1::sub_match<const char *> *>` ?

I was expecting param will be deduced to be `std:::cmatch`
Can you please explain how param deduction is working here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::cmatch` is an alias for `std::match_results<char const*>`; you want `std::sub_match<char const*>`, whose alias is `std::csub_match`.

```
std::for_each(cm.begin(), cm.end(), [](const std::csub_match &s) { ... }
```

Comment: My question is why its `csub_match` why not `cmatch` ?

Comment: @NulledPointer : Because [`std::match_results<Iter>::value_type` is `std::sub_match<Iter>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results). There's nothing special about `match_results` here, this is how any iterator works.

Comment: I think Im stilling missing how iterator works. ill look up that first. meanwhile ill accept your answer