# c++ member types

Tags: c++

This question arises from question related to [c++ regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39844093/is-this-c-template-param-deduction-incorrect) I just asked.

In online cpp references e.g. [match_results](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results), what does `value_type` in "Member types" section means? Is this some standard way of defining classes? How to read this whole "Member Types" section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Member types are just `typedef`s (or sometimes full classes) that are useful for using and/or somehow related to the class itself.

As you ask about member types in general, lets take `std::vector` as example:

```
template < class T, class Alloc = allocator<T> > class vector;
```

It's a template with type `T` (and an allocator, doesn't matter).

Now, `std::vector` contains an member type `std::vector::value_type`, which always is defined to be the same type as `T`. Eg for `vector<int>`, `std::vector::value_type` is the same as `int`, and you can use it to define new variables etc.
Similar, there are `pointer` and `reference` and some other things which resolve to `int*` and `int&`.

Then, there is `size_type`, which defines a variable suitable to hold all possible vector length values ... Because eg. it's usually different on X86 and X64 (and, for some classes, it can depend on the implementation, and...), it's useful to have somthing like that.

And so on...